# How do I install MySQL with –with-federated-storage-engine on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.10

Well honestly the title says it all.  I am new to server install and stuff and basically want this for testing purposes for a web app I am building. I have ubuntu up and running but want to get mysql running with the federated storage engine enabled by default.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Aron

Answer (score 2):

federated engine seems to be disabled by default, at least in ubuntu 10.10.
you can enable it by adding

```
[mysqld]
...
federated
...
```

in my.cnf

i'm on ubuntu 10.10, default mysql install.

```
mysql> create table local3(a integer, b integer) ENGINE=FEDERATED CONNECTION='mysql://root@localhost:3306/t1/remote';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
mysql> show warnings;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from local3;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

you may also want to check for "skip-federated" parameter in your config file(s) and eventually remove it if you want federated.
few quick notes,

- mysqld --print-defaults will give you
  a hint as of what args is mysqld
  started with after parsing the config
  file(s)
- mysqld --verbose --help will    not
  mention the "federated" parameter.
- creating a table with federated
  engine when federated is disabled
  will just 2 warnings and no errors.
  the table will be created with the
  default engine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably too late for the OP but I have spent hours searching for how to enable the federated engine on a yum mysql build so I thought I should put the answer here for future googlers:

Distro is Fedora 14, MySQL is a standard yum mysql-server (& mysql-devel, not sure if that is relevant for this federated engine install tho') install v5.1.55.

To enable the federated engine:

Check the file 'ha_federated.so' exists. In the distro I am using it is in    '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin', if it does not exist anywhere then this fix is not for you.

Start your mysql shell with a user with insert access to the mysql.plugin table.

Enter "install plugin federated soname 'ha_federated.so';" (without the double quotes)

The message "Query OK, 1 warning", should display. "show warnings" should show a warning "1123 ...plugin is disabled", this is expected.

To check if the plugin has been installed run "select * from mysql.plugin"

Exit the MySQL shell.

Edit "my.cnf" (generally found in /etc) and insert (or uncomment) the line that contains the single word "federated"

Stop & restart the mysqld service.

Fire up the shell and create a table using the federated engine, if the above has worked then "show create table newtablename" should show that the engine is using the federated engine.